# How to use Fiddler in C# with a proxy?

Tags: fiddler

I've been using `Fiddler` in `C#`.

So far I'm able to intercept requests. However, I need to set a proxy. I did so, the proxy is set.

In `Proxy Settings` Windows' form, I have for `HTTP` and `Secure`: `127.0.0.1` for `Proxy address to use` and for the `Port`, `8888`.

This is the same that is done when I use Fiddler application directly.

However, when I set it through my `C#` code, instead of using `Fiddler`, I can't navigate. My pages give me the message:

```
Your connection is not secure
```

What more do I need to do? What `Fiddler` do that I'm missing to correctly set a proxy?

Comment: I have the same issue like you. Waiting for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually if it cant make a secure connection, you need to [trust Fiddler's root certificate](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/TrustFiddlerRootCert) on your development PC. If you are using Firefox you will have to do an [additional step](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/FirefoxHTTPS) to trust the certificate inside FF.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I noticed that other browsers do work. I really appreciated it thanks!!

Comment: I noticed the page display is sometime different. For example, google. Why is that?